# How can I control matrix zero to be 1 by predetermined column in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have some list of column like this:

```
   res = [[2],[3, 4],[0],[5]]
```

Then, I need to change this `zr` zero matrix 4X4 to be 1 following column in `res` list above; For example: the first row plots 1 in column 2, the second row plots 1 in column 3 and 4, the third row will have no plot due to [0] and the fourth row plots 1 in column 5.

```
  zr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]]
```

Target:

```
  zr = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
                 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]]
```

My current coding has a wrong change when some members in res equal to [0]:

```
for i, x in enumerate (res):
    if x==0:
        continue
    else:
        for j in x:
            zr[i][j-1] = 1
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank You.

Comment: Why did you tag R?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you want to do. This will skip the line if it finds [0] as an inner list.

```
for i, x in enumerate (res):
    if x == [0]: 
        continue
    else:
        for j in x:
            zr[i][j-1] = 1

print(zr)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]]
```

What you were doing wrong is you were trying to compare x (which is a list) with 0. That's always False.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `put` from `numpy`, e.g.,

```
for i in range(len(zr)):
    np.put(zr[i], np.array(res[i])-1, 1)
```

and you will see

```
>>> print(zr)
[[0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]]
```